# c# default application - how to get the file content?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, default

I need to write an WPF application, that can be launched as default application at doubleclick on the file with extension `.specext` in files explorer.

The problem appears... at the beginning. I don't know where can I find the file content or even the information, that the application was launched on opening the file.

Where should I start searching? How to get this file content?

**Edit:**

I know how to associate file with an application. I don't know how to display its' content when the application is launched.

**Edit 2 (solution):**

Currently I'm using `Environment.CommandLine` to get the file path.

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780319/how-to-create-a-custom-file-extension-in-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082889/how-to-change-filetype-association-in-the-registry, and https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20file%20extension%20association

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I didn't found there what I'm looking for.