# Associate a file extension with WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, file-extension

I have a nice little assignment organizer that I want to add a backup option to. But I don't want it in an ordinary xml file or someother file because of the possibility of file corruption. So how can I make a file extension that the program knows and can save to and open with a .asog file extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Vista generate the icon for documents associated to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580827/how-does-vista-generate-the-icon-for-documents-associated-to-my-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
[How does Vista generate the icon for documents associated to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580827/how-does-vista-generate-the-icon-for-documents-associated-to-my-application)

The accepted answer explains icons *and* file associations.

It doesn't matter that your app uses WPF.  The file associations don't care what GUI framework your app uses.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to associate a file with extension (.magi) with your WPF application, I advise you to use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to do that.

For example, I developed an WPF application called MAGI. We associate an icon to "*.magi" file and when a user clicks on a "*.magi" file it launches the application and opens it directly in the application.

[image: Open file extension in Wpf application]

---

#### Use InnoSetup to modify the registry easily

Just add this instructino in your iss file :

```
[Setup]
ChangesAssociations=yes

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".magi"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyMAGIApplication"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyMAGIApplication"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Program MAGI"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyMAGIApplication\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\MAGI.EXE,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyMAGIApplication\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\MAGI.EXE"" ""%1"""
```

#### Parse the arguments in the "Startup" method

We use the `Startup` property in the main Xaml, in order to call your parser like a useful main method.

```
<Application x:Class="MAGI.View.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         Startup="AppStartupMainMagi" >
</Application>
```

And in the code-behind we add this method

```
/// <summary>
/// Call with Startup property in App.xaml
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void AppStartupMainMAGI(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    if (arguments.GetLength(0) > 1)
    {
        if (arguments[1].EndsWith(".magi"))
        {
            string filePathFormMainArgs = arguments[1];
            if(isFileMagiValid(filePathFormMainArgs)) 
            {
                // Step 1 : deserialize filePathFormMainArgs
                // Step 2 : call the view "File oepn" in the application"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Call the view "welcome page application"
    }
}
```

Comment: tried, it's working, but application crashed, because content folder access denied !. How to get items like icons, images from content folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file extension with either a Setup project or a ClickOnce install.  Once you have it setup, a user can double click on a .asog file and your app will be invoked with the filename as the first entry in the arguments array of main.